# No consigo que el multiselect de Yii2 muestre los seleccionados y los no seleccionados con update

Tags: php, yii2, model, model-view-controller

Tengo problemas al cargar el `array` de datos del modelo para que cuando llegue a la vista el `multiselect` que tengo tenga seleccionado los datos correspondientes, solo me salen los datos seleccionados y me gustaría que salieran los seleccionados y los no seleccionados para poder editar la misma en el caso que se necesitara.

En el `create` no tengo problema porque solo tiene que cargar un `array` el modelo categoría.

Actualmente al cargar en el dropdown me salen las categorías de la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo me gustaría es que me salieran seleccionadas en este caso la 4 y la 7 y las otras hasta diez no pero poder seleccionarlas
**formUpdate**

```
<div class="fotos-form">

<div class="row col-lg-6">

    <?php

    Pjax::begin([
    // Pjax options
    ]);

     $form = ActiveForm::begin([
             'options' => [
                     'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                     'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                     'data' => ['pjax' => true],
                 ]]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($categoria, 'id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => $categorias,
        'language' => 'es',
        'options' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Añadir Categorias',
                'id' => 'nombre',
                'prompt' => 'Selecciona Categoría...',
                'selected' => 'selected'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
                'tags' => true,
                'allowClear' => true,
            'maximumInputLength' => 10
        ],
    ]);

    ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'fechaCreado')->textInput(['disabled' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'fechaActualizado')->textInput(['disabled' => true]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>


</div>
<div class="row col-lg-6">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'nombre')->fileInput(['class' => 'btn btn-default btn-file']) ?>
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <?php $url = $model->getImageUrl($model->id);?>
                <?= Html::img($url, ['width'=>'360px','class' =>'img-responsive img-rounded']); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    <?php

    ActiveForm::end();
    Pjax::end();
    ?>
</div>
```

**función controlador:**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $categoria = new Categorias();
    $categorias = ArrayHelper::map(Categorias::find()->where(['fotos' => $id])->joinWith('tienens')->all(), 'id','id');

    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'categoria' => $categoria,
        'categorias' =>$categorias,
    ]);
}
```

no consigo juntar las dos cosas o cargo el array con todos los datos o el array con los seleccionados pero no consigo que me cargue el multiselect con los elementos seleccionados y los no seleccionados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrada la solución mirando el api Krajee detalladamente sobre todo el uso de tags

[krajee.com/widget-details/select2](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2)

solución primeros cambios en controlador

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $categoria = new Categorias();
        $categorias = Categorias::find()->select('categorias.id')->where(['fotos' => $id])->joinWith('tienens')->asArray()->all();
        $listaCategorias = ArrayHelper::map(Categorias::find()->all(), 'id','nombre');

        foreach($categorias as $data){
            $catSelecionadas[] = $data['id'];
        }
        $categoria->id = $catSelecionadas;

        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'categoria' => $categoria,
            'listaCategorias' => $listaCategorias
        ]);
    }
```

y en vista en el dropdown

```
<?= $form->field($categoria, 'id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
            'data' => $listaCategorias,
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Selecciona una categoría ...', 'multiple' => true, 'maintainOrder' => true],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'tags' => true,
                'tokenSeparators' => [',', ' '],
                'maximumInputLength' => 10
            ],
        ])->label('Listado de Categorías');;

        ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias a todos los que me habéis ayudado y espero que pueda servir a otros.

Answer (score 1):

me parece que tu error es pasar el map donde va el modelo y pasar un arreglo de objetos del modelo donde va la data mapeada

tendría que ir así

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => $categoria,
        'Select2::THEME_KRAJEE',
        'language' => 'es',
        'options' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Añadir Categorias',
                'id' => 'nombre',
                'prompt' => 'Selecciona Categoría...',
                'selected' => 'selected'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
                'tags' => true,
                'allowClear' => true,
            'maximumInputLength' => 10
        ],
    ]);

    ?>
```

Comment: el problema está en que si lo pongo como dices en el multiselect me salen solo los seleccionados y no puedo escoger ninguno más solo quitar alguno y lo que me gustaría es que con el multiselect me llegará todos y los que tienen  estuvieran seleccionados, edito la pregunta para como queda

Comment: puedes poner imágenes de como sale actualmente, y una de cómo te gustaría que saliera? (aunque sea editada)